# Boost Spirit Qi rule for XML comment tag

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

EBNF rule for XML comment tag is:

```
Comment ::= '<!--' ((Char - '-') | ('-' (Char - '-')))* '-->'
```

How to get Boost Spirit Qi rule for it?

```
using boost::spirit::qi::ascii::char_;
using boost::spirit::qi::lit;
comment = lit("<!--") >> *((~char_('-') >> char_) | (char_('-') >> ~char_('-'))) >> lit("-->");
```

This is my the best try, but not correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd phrase it more directly:

```
comment = "<!--" > *(qi::char_ - "--") > "-->";
```

Remember to make the rule lexeme (disable/ignore skipper). (See [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using It = std::string::const_iterator;

int main() {
    qi::rule<It> comment; // lexeme
    comment = "<!--" > *(qi::char_ - "--") > "-->";
}
```

Comment: My final test code example is:  `namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;  
std::string s = "<!-- My favorite operators are > and <!-->";  
std::string::const_iterator f = s.cbegin();  
bool r = qi::phrase_parse(f, s.cend(), qi::lexeme["<!--" >> *(~qi::ascii::char_("--")) >> "-->"], qi::space);`  
1. I've used sequence (>>) instead of expectation (>) parser, otherwise exception handling must be used.  
2. I've wrapped whole expression into `lexeme[]`, otherwise loosing the fist space after "<!--" happens because of skipper.  Thank you @sehe

Comment: First off, comments are not suited for code. See [here instead](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63d4b5f6b1b5df7f).

Comment: 1. that's your option. However, keep in mind it *is* by definition invalid XML, so you may want to prevent back-tracking the grammar (which is why expectation points exist).

Comment: 2. Good eye for detail. That was also correct in my rule, which doesn't even declare a skipper. Note that my [counter-offer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63d4b5f6b1b5df7f) simplifies by not even using a skipper as well. This is why I [linked to the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965) for backgrounds.

Comment: 3. You may need better eye for detail, though: [because your modification doesn't do what you think it does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d4370bed585e597). That's because `a = qi::char_(".....")` is a **charset**, and so is `~a` (see [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char.html#spirit.qi.reference.char.char.expression_semantics)). You **need** a literat "--" match. See my original answer, [reflected here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2429abdca8f1ba19). #cheers

Answer (score 1):

`~char_('-')` corresponds to `(Char - '-')`.
The first part:

```
(~char_('-') >> char_)
```

should be

```
~char_('-')
```

alone.

Otherwise this `char_` could match a `-` and the second part `(char_('-') >> ~char_('-')` match `->` on the next turn.

Comment: I agree, the first part should be `~char_('-')`, but in this case `*(~char_('-') | (char_('-') >> ~char_('-')))` compilation fails — because the first part produces one symbol and the second two. Some attempts to use expectation parser (`>`) or/and `omit[]` in the second were unsuccessful.Thank you anyway.